# Airflow scheduler to run a DAG on all days excepting Tuesday is not working

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to run an Airflow DAG at 04:30 UTC time. I want to run it on all days excepting Tuesday. I have set the `schedule_interval` in the following way:

```
schedule_interval='30 04 * * 0,1,3,4,5,6'
```

However, I see the DAG is not running at the anticipated time instances. If I run manually, then it runs fine. So there is no error in any other place. Could you please point out the mistake in scheduler? Is it not the right approach to exclude a particular day from the scheduler?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The schedule looks correct. Can you give more information? What is your start_date? Are you are running DAG for past dates? If you don't enable `catchup=true` the DAG won't run for past dates.

Comment: How about you tell us when it _is_ running and when you _expected_ it to run.

Comment: make sure the machine you are trying to run is in UTC timezone..else change the time according to the machines time-zome.